# How can I apply Lock/ReadWriteLock to synchronize an object?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, synchronization

I am running a Servlet, in which there is a third party Servlet filter performing some validation based on the rules defined in an externalized xml. The Servlet parses the xml into an object and the Servlet Filter reads the object for validation.
As this Servlet is provided by third party so I cannot modify/extend it because of agreement .

There is a scheduled task reading the externalized xml and updating the object  periodically.

In concurrency scenario if there is a case that the scheduled task is updating the object while there is a request asking the Servlet Filter for validation. So the rules is clearly not updated for validation.

What I want to ensure is whenever there is an updating of the object happens, any validation in progress should be paused. So that each validation in the Servlet Filter is reading the updated rules defined in xml.

Just scanned that ReadWriteLock seems to be a perfect solution. But it needs to add readLock().lock() in the action of reading an object, which seems not feasible for my case (As mentioned above I cannot modify nor extend the Filter).

May I know if there is any doable solutions?

Supplement some source code to clarify the description
The XMLObject and ThirdPartyFilter are provided by 3rd party in jar.
    class XMLObject{
        private List rules;
        //getter and setter
    }

```
class ThirdPartyFilter implements Filter{
     private static XMLObject xmlObj;
     static{
         //some code to parse the external xml to get the rules
         xmlObj = new XMLObject;
         xmlObj.setRules(rules);
     }
     doFilter(){
         List<Rule> rules = xmlObj.getRules();
         //do validation here

     }
}
```

The scheduler is using reflection to retrieve the static xmlObj which is initialized in the Filter above.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
class Scheduler{
     @Scheduled(fixedDelay=600000) //execute this function every 10 minutes
     public void updateXMLObj(){
         //parse external xml and update the xmlObj
     }
}
```

The above codes are already running well in the Servlet application.

The concern is that when Scheduler.updateXMLObj() is being executed, in the meanwhile the ThirdPartyFilter is performing a validation in doFilter(), the validation rules are not up-to-date. 
I hope that if Scheduler.updateXMLObj() is in progress, the XMLObject will be locked so that ThirdPartyFilter cannot read it for validation. Is it doable ?

Comment: Update the questions with your code

Comment: Isn't there a filter _chain_ in Servlet? Couldn't you place your filters before and after your black box, and add locking there?

Comment: If you define your filters in the `web.xml` file then you can controle the order of their execution, so just add a new filter before the 3rd party one and do the lock in that new filter.

Comment: Also "whenever there is an updating of the object happens, any validation in progress should be paused." is not what you want. You want that updating of the object won't happen if there's a validation in progress, and vice versa. Unless you really want to validate half with an old version and the second half with a new version.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes. there is a filter chain in web.xml. Could you please show how to implement the lock in another filter placed before the 3rd party one? I have supplemented the code for your reference. Thx

Comment: @MarcoFerrari source code added. appreciated it that if you can give any hint , thx !

Comment: @Kayaman yes,you are right. do you have any idea how to implement it ? thx

Comment: @jmli A somewhat clumsy (but basically working) implementation would be sticking a static `Lock` or `Semaphore` in the filter class that will be running before `ThirdPartyFilter` and both the filter and `Scheduler` would lock/acquire on the object.

Comment: The requirement doesn't make much sense. Since the rules are updated on a regular basis, and not immediately after they change, basically all checks are potentially running on out of date rules. Why would the filter be paused while reading the XML file? Just consider that the rules are up-to date once they are written to xmlObj, not while they're read and parsed. Or just imagine that your scheduler runs every 10 minutes minus some milliseconds, which doesn't change anything.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes you are right. I got a bit confused at the beginning when analyzing the requirement. Now I am thinking to adopt ReadWriteLock to make it. Applied write lock on Scheduler when updating xmlObj and read lock on a new filter before thirdPartyFilter